# EXCEL: IF statement with AND and NOT with SUMIFS

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Please can I have help: I have an IF statement in Excel.  In the first Statement I want it to be linked to NET transactions and ALL - $C$6="NET",$C$5="ALL" - this works fine.  I next want a statement to say NET transactions but NOT all.

How do I add a rule for the NOT part.  The first two IF statements work, the 3rd IF statement is causing errors.

```
    =IF((AND($C$6="NET",$C$5="ALL")),SUMIFS(DATA!$I:$I,DATA!$A:$A,'Transactions'!$D$8,DATA!$B:$B,'Transactions'!D$9,DATA!$C:$C,'Transactions'!$B11,DATA!$D:$D,'Transactions'!$C11),
IF((AND($C$6="GROSS",$C$5="ALL")),SUMIFS(DATA!$J:$J,DATA!$A:$A,'Transactions'!$D$8,DATA!$B:$B,'Transactions'!D$9,DATA!$C:$C,'Transactions'!$B11,DATA!$D:$D,'Transactions'!$C11)),
IF((AND($C$6="GROSS",NOT($C$5="ALL"))),SUMIFS(DATA!$J:$J,DATA!$A:$A,'Transactions'!$D$8,DATA!$B:$B,'Transactions'!D$9,DATA!$C:$C,'Transactions'!$B11,DATA!$D:$D,'Transactions'!$C11)))
```

Comment: Am I seeing this right that the second and the third `SumIfs()` parameter lists are equal? If you have "if this, do something and in another case, do that same something", you might better say "if this or in another case, do something". That's easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misisng a `T` and you want the `)` for the second `IF` to be at the end:

```
=IF((AND($C$6="NET",$C$5="ALL")),SUMIFS(DATA!$I:$I,DATA!$A:$A,'Transactions'!$D$8,DATA!$B:$B,'Transactions'!D$9,DATA!$C:$C,'Transactions'!$B11,DATA!$D:$D,'Transactions'!$C11),
IF((AND($C$6="GROSS",$C$5="ALL")),SUMIFS(DATA!$J:$J,DATA!$A:$A,'Transactions'!$D$8,DATA!$B:$B,'Transactions'!D$9,DATA!$C:$C,'Transactions'!$B11,DATA!$D:$D,'Transactions'!$C11),
IF((AND($C$6="GROSS",NOT($C$5="ALL"))),SUMIFS(DATA!$J:$J,DATA!$A:$A,'Transactions'!$D$8,DATA!$B:$B,'Transactions'!D$9,DATA!$C:$C,'Transactions'!$B11,DATA!$D:$D,'Transactions'!$C11))))
```